# How to set button text based on test of ALL dropdown values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list. Each item in the list is a dropdown.

The initial or selected value of each dropdown is `A`.

There is also a button present.

When I change the dropdown value it should change the button text. This  is currently working.

My issue is when the selected dropdown value is `A` the button text is `Fixed`. For all other values it is `Not Fixed`.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8qxZRhNOryGl2f9NFEz5?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button>{{btn}}</button>
  <div ng-repeat="x in arr">{{x}}
    <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="change(selectedValue)">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Currently all dropdown show `A` and button text is `Fixed`.
2. Change the first drodown value `A` to `B`.

   - Button text is now `Not Fixed`.
3. Change the second drodown value `A` to `B`.

   - Button text remains `Not Fixed`.
4. Change the value of the first dropdown to `A` leaving the second drodown value as `B`.

   - Actual behaviour:

     - Button text is `Fixed`.
   - Desired behaviour:

     - Button text should be `Not Fixed` because one of the dropdown values is not `A`.

**Question:** How do I alter the code below to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
$scope.change = function(value){
  console.log(value);
  if(value !='A'){
    $scope.btn = ' NOT Fixed';
  }else{
    $scope.btn = 'Fixed';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following rule: when all dropdown values is A, then the text of the button must be "Fixed", otherwise it is "Not Fixed".

You are not checking properly for the condition. Your piece of code will set the button text to 'Fixed' if at any moment the value of the last selected dropdown is not "A". It does not take in account all the other dropdown's values. This is a way to achieve want you want to:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.btn = 'Fixed';
  $scope.arr = [1, 2, 3];
  $scope.selectedValues = {
    [1]: 'A',
    [2]: 'A',
    [3]: 'A'
  };

  $scope.change = function() {
    if (
      Object
        .values($scope.selectedValues)
        .every(function(e) { return e === 'A'; })
    ) {
      $scope.btn = 'Fixed';
    } else {
      $scope.btn = 'NOT Fixed';
    }
  }

  $scope.change();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button>{{btn}}</button>
  <div ng-repeat="x in arr">{{x}}
    <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="selectedValues[x]" ng-change="change(selectedValue)">
                <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>C</option>
          </select>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is two issue u r using `arrow` function which is not supported in all brower .second `every`

Comment: You are right, changed it to support all browsers. But the result remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

> If you again change the value of first dropdown B to A .it show button text is Fixed why ??

The text is 'Fixed' when selecting 'A' because your if statement says "if the value is **not** a, assign `$scope.btn` to `' NOT Fixed'`, otherwise assign `$scope.btn` to `'Fixed'`.

> Fixed `text only show when each dropdown value is` A`.

In order to accomplish this, you'll have to approach your assignment of `$scope.btn` differently. Rather than only referencing the passed in value, you'll also need to take a look at the values of your 2 other `select` menus before reassigning the variable.